# Vertical Scroll bar with QtableWidget

Tags: qt, qtablewidget

This problem is observed in Mac only. In Winows 7 and XP, everything works fine.

In QTable Widget, I am adding some items in certain columns using `setCellWidget()`. Whereas, to add items in other columns of the same row I am using `setItem()`.
 When I tried to use vertical scroll bar, the items added by using `setItem()` scroll properly. But the items added by `setCellWidget()` do not scroll at all . They are frozen.
 What I tried – [1] I tried setting the stylesheet – QString scrollStyleSheet = “QTableWidget {}”; // tried few variations too , but this works the best `ui->deviceGridTable->setStyleSheet(scrollStyleSheet );`

It works fine, so long as I do not scroll, when items are getting added. Before adding new items or after adding new items, if I scroll, it works fine. However, if I scroll, while new iterms are being added one by one , it shows the same old ugly characterstics which I just described.

[2] I tried setting `VerticalScrollMode` to `ScrollPerPixel`. It does not work at all.

What else can I try to fix the problem of vertical scrolling while items are detting added ? (Only for those items which are added using `setCellWidget()`.

The problem is only on Mac OSX 10.8.1. I am using Qt 4.8.3

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
tableWidget.setVisible(0)
tableWidget.setSortingEnabled(0)
... populate tableWidget here ...
tableWidget.setSortingEnabled(1)
tableWidget.setVisible(1)
```

If you do not use sorting then try only with visibility.